# Can I write a range in [0-1) style with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, delimiters

I want to give a range of degree in my document.
One end is explicitly inside the range, while the other is outside.

Is there a "correct" SI way of writing a range with an inclusive and exclusive end (i.e., left-open right-closed interval or vice versa)?

I'm already using siunitx for ranges: `\SIrange{0}{180}{\degree}` -> 0 bis 180°

There is one example in the [documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/special/SIunits.pdf) (page 46) that seems to be somewhat similar, but i don't think that it applies to my problem:

`\SIrange[range-units = brackets]{2}{4}{\degreeCelsius}` -> `( 2 to 4 ) °C`

Comment: Hi! I think the title is fine. I made couple small corrections in the post [(see the revision)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/195951/revisions), if you don't like them, you can of course revert them. And a nice question btw!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set `open-bracket` or `close-bracket`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SIrange[range-units = brackets,open-bracket = {[}]{2}{4}{\degreeCelsius}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this is entirely illogical :-) The `siunitx` package is about physical units, and you can't _measure_ an open interval, only some real value (with an uncertainty you might or might not think about).

Comment: If you measure an angle you always have [0-360). I measured an rectangle object without a defined front, so i measured [0-180). The scales that end in the beginning are tricky objects ^^

Comment: @JosephWright That's also my opinion.

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz, for angles you would need the non-existing `\angrange`. @JosephWright, maybe this is some missing feature?